# Mysql trigger with if condition, update parent table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this query in my php files and need to create a mysql trigger to store the success state in mysql:

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(repstate = 0, 1, 0)) AS repstatezero,
SUM(IF(repstate = 1, 1, 0)) AS repstateone,
SUM(IF(repstate = 2, 1, 0)) AS repstatetwo,
SUM(IF(repstate = 3, 1, 0)) AS repstatethree
FROM positions 
WHERE order_id = $id 

// Snippet from PDO foreach
if(
$row['repstatezero'] == 0 AND
$row['repstateone'] == 0 AND
$row['repstatetwo'] == 0 AND
$row['repstatethree'] >= 1 ) {
echo "<span class='badge badge-success'>Success</span>";   
}
```

The value of order.state should be set to 3 if all positions.repstate`X` are 0 of the related reference ID positions.order_id

This is what i have:

```
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE TRIGGER update_orderstate
  BEFORE UPDATE ON positions
  FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN repstate=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS repstatezero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN repstate=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS repstateone,
    SUM(CASE WHEN repstate=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS repstatetwo,
    SUM(CASE WHEN repstate=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS repstatestree

    FROM positions 

    ....
    END

DELIMITER ;
```

Here i stuck. I tried some subsequent if-conditions but fail.

Thanks.

Reference tables *(child)state=repstate in code snippet*:

Orders:

```
| ID | order      | (parent)state  |
| 1  | some text  | 0              |
| 2  | some text  | 3              |
| 3  | some text  | 0              |
```

Positions:

```
| ID | order_id   | (child)state   |
| 1  | 1          | 0              |
| 2  | 3          | 1              |
| 3  | 2          | 3              |
| 4  | 2          | 3              |
```

*In this case order ID 2 should also set to 3 related the positions.id 3+4.*

After all child-states of the same order_id are manually set to 3 (3=completed), the (parent)state should automatic also set to 3.

Another example of an shop: If all positions are delivered, the order is complete.

Comment: Please add the table structure of your two tables and some sample data and the expected outcome with concrete examples (e.g. if you update this row in table 1 to some other value, and have this row in table 2, the trigger should do change the row in table 2 to the following); at least for me it is completely unclear what you are trying to do here. If your parent table from the title is the same as the child table (you aren't very precise about thatm but it looks a bit like it): mysql does not allow you to change a different row in the same table, just the one row you are updating.

Comment: Thanks, i added the data.